# Angular: add more button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form. There is an add more button Every time I click on add more, I push a new instance of a class to an array. Also I have a delete row function which is responsible for removing the added item from the array.
Then I have an ngFor loop over the array, and it works correctly, but if I add 3 rows and then try to remove the first one and then click on add more button then the data of the second and the third rows goes empty, but they still exist on their model. (`ngModel`)

```
<form  #manageEmailsForm="ngForm" name="manageEmailsForm">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of partners;let x = index">
        {{item.email|json}}
        {{j}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <mat-input-container>
                <input matInput
                       placeholder="email"
                       [name]="'piEmail'+x"

                       #piEmail="ngModel"
                       [(ngModel)]="item.email" >
                <mat-error
                        *ngIf="piEmail.errors && !piEmail.errors['required'] && piEmail.errors['email']">
                    {{"system-user.piemail format is incorrect"|translate}}
                </mat-error>
            </mat-input-container>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="deletePartner(x)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My delete and add button:

```
    deletePartner(index) {
       this.partners.splice(index, 1);
    }
    addAnotherPartner() {
      this.partners.push(new Partner());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely unexpected behavior because your form assumes your button is submit type by default.

When declaring buttons inside `<form> </form>` which aren't meant to submit
make sure they're declared as buttons, otherwise treated with submit event like behavior

In example

```
<button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="deletePartner(x)">
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

If you want to test this theory, change nothing, and simply add an onSubmit() function to your form

```
<form  #manageEmailsForm="ngForm" 
       name="manageEmailsForm" 
       (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(manageEmailsForm)">
```

Comment: I add type="button" but problem is exits

Comment: @hessamzaheri add `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(manageEmailsForm)`,   and create a function `onSubmit(form: NgForm) {console.log('submitted!');}` to make sure nothing else calls it. You need to make sure all non-submit buttons are declared as button, like the add one you haven't shown here

Comment: @hessamzaheri, did you try to add an onSubmit function for ngSubmit to see if anything else is happening?